# MATLAB tic toc equivalent in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, timing

I have a program in Mathematica and the equivalent program in MATLAB. I want to do a series of test to see how they compare. To do this I want to calculate the run time of the codes, for this I am using the tic toc functionality in MATLAB. For Mathematica I have tried using AbsoluteTiming but I haven't found a way to implement it in my whole code only in one singular line.

Kind regards

Comment: Anything useful in the [Mathematica documentation for timing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TimeMeasurementAndOptimization.html)? e.g. [TimeUsed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeUsed.html) which you could get before and after whatever code you want to calculate the difference

Comment: I would suggest asking in the Mathematica specific site, most users are there and not in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Be careful with `tic` and `toc` when timing code. It’s OK for code that runs a long time, but not for short code. Prefer `timeit` for code that finishes in a few seconds or less.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
`Now[[1]]`
at the beginning and end of your evaluations (assuming that you are wanting to work out the time it takes to run multiple cells).

```
In[1]:= start = Now[[1]];

In[2]:= eval = Table[x^2, {x, 1, 100}];

In[3]:= end = Now[[1]];

In[4]:= end - start

Out[4]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.055699}
```

The output is how long mathematica took to evaluate the cells in {years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds}.